# Python Lists.What am I missing?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

```
from random import *
def f(one):
    x=randrange(0,len(one))
    y=randrange(0,len(one))
    return(one)
print(one(["20","40","60"]))
```

the function is supposed to take an input parameter a list of strings and generates two random numbers between 0 and the length of the list but how do you return the list with the slice between the two numbers removed.

Answer (score 2):

First you are not calling the function you've created, you must:

```
print( f(["20","40","60"]) )
```

Second, your function `f()` is not doing anything, is just creating two variables `x and y` but returning the same list it received as parameter.

And to return the sliced list:

```
from random import *
def f(one):
    x=randrange(0,len(one))
    y=randrange(0,len(one))
    print (x, y)
    return one[x:y]
print(f(["20","40","60"]))
```

Remember that `randrange(x, y)` returns a value between `x` and `y - 1`

Comment: @user2924008 then click on `accept` at the top-left side of the answer.

Comment: It seems like that user doesn't exist anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The sublist of a list `one` from index `i` up to (but not including!) index `j` is written in Python as `one[i:j]`.  I think you can figure out the rest from here.